# JavaScript - passing variables through the URL: #var=val vs ?var=val

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass variables through the URL that will only be consumed on the client-side javascript. What is the difference between passing them as:

> ?var1=val1&var2=val2

vs

> #var1=val1&var2=val2

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one  is search, and the second one is hash.

Search is sent to the server, but hash is not.

There is an event for hashchange, but not for search.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Answer (score 1):

The `?` (query portion) gets sent to the server, the `#` (hash portion) does not.

When the hash portion is used, it will not reload the page. When the query portion is used, it will reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

The first one `?var1=val1&var2=val2` is a query string and let's the browser make a request.

The second one is a fragment and doesn't do a new request.

Answer (score 0):

"#" is generally a link clicked on the page, working as a page anchor.

"?" are parameters that are passed via client/server.

Answer (score 0):

The server will never see the hash tag variables, so that state cannot be replicated on the server (therefore, a search bot won't get it)

It's slightly easier to parse the standard `?name=value` since `location.search` gives you that part of the URL

Changing the `?` will cause the page to refresh and setting `#` won't